# SQL Bulk Import fails with: Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" (Again)

Tags: sql-server, import, bulkinsert

This works in my lab, where the SQL server is running on Ubuntu Server. We just built a new SQL server on Windows Server 2019, migrated the database to it and the import script fails with the dreaded: Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Here is the table I am trying to populate

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ZZTEMP_Companies] (
[id] bigint NULL,
[additionalAddressInformation] varchar(100) NULL,
[address1] varchar(128) NULL,
[address2] varchar(128) NULL,
[alternatePhone1] varchar(25) NULL,
[alternatePhone2] varchar(25) NULL,
[apiVendorID] int NULL,
[assetValue] decimal(18, 2) NULL,
[billToCompanyLocationID] int NULL,
[billToAdditionalAddressInformation] varchar(100) NULL,
[billingAddress1] varchar(150) NULL,
[billingAddress2] varchar(150) NULL,
[billToAddressToUse] int NULL,
[billToAttention] varchar(50) NULL,
[billToCity] varchar(50) NULL,
[billToCountryID] int NULL,
[billToState] varchar(128) NULL,
[billToZipCode] varchar(50) NULL,
[city] varchar(100) NULL,
[classification] int NULL,
[companyCategoryID] int NULL,
[companyName] varchar(100) NULL,
[companyNumber] varchar(50) NULL,
[companyType] smallint NULL,
[competitorID] int NULL,
[countryID] int NULL,
[createDate] datetime NULL,
[createdByResourceID] int NULL,
[currencyID] int NULL,
[fax] varchar(25) NULL,
[impersonatorCreatorResourceID] int NULL,
[invoiceEmailMessageID] int NULL,
[invoiceMethod] int NULL,
[invoiceNonContractItemsToParentCompany] char(10) NULL,
[invoiceTemplateID] int NULL,
[isActive] char(10) NULL,
[isClientPortalActive] char(10) NULL,
[isEnabledForComanaged] char(10) NULL,
[isTaskFireActive] char(10) NULL,
[isTaxExempt] char(10) NULL,
[lastActivityDate] datetime NULL,
[lastTrackedModifiedDateTime] datetime NULL,
[marketSegmentID] int NULL,
[ownerResourceID] int NULL,
[parentCompanyID] int NULL,
[phone] varchar(25) NULL,
[postalCode] varchar(10) NULL,
[purchaseOrderTemplateID] int NULL,
[quoteEmailMessageID] int NULL,
[quoteTemplateID] int NULL,
[sicCode] varchar(32) NULL,
[state] varchar(40) NULL,
[stockMarket] varchar(10) NULL,
[stockSymbol] varchar(10) NULL,
[surveyCompanyRating] decimal(18, 2) NULL,
[taxID] varchar(50) NULL,
[taxRegionID] int NULL,
[territoryID] int NULL,
[webAddress] varchar(255) NULL,
[UserDefinedFields] varchar(MAX) NULL,
[BillCycle] char(1) NULL)
```

Here is the script:

```
BULK INSERT DataWarehouse..ZZTEMP_Companies
  FROM 'E:\ETL\DataWarehouse_ETL\Companies.csv'
  WITH
    (
      FORMAT='csv',
      FIELDQUOTE ='',
      FIRSTROW=2,
      FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
      ROWTERMINATOR='\r\n'
    )
```

...and here is the csv:
[CSV](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1n4VMXky1qyM-juguhYPSXcn7g0cbCWtC?usp=sharing)

If I use the Import Wizard in Toad, the import works fine.  I am betting that the issue might be related to permissions because the Toad import is running under my login while the SQL script executes under the NT Service account.

Comment: You are probably guessing right, have you checked the SQL Server service account is granted filesystem access permissions to the source folder.

Comment: I just went in and granted the NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER service Full Access to the file system folder where the source csv is located, restarted the service and the message is the same.

Comment: You could also try with just selecting from `openrowset(bulk...)`

Comment: Considering that I have it running in my lab, I'd prefer to not change any of the scripts.  There MUST be a way to get the Bulk Insert method to work.   Does anyone know of any unusual circumstances that trigger this message?